# "Otherwise" or "If not", What's the difference?

Tags: nouns

I'm really confused about this and I need someone to help me.

For example :

> You will get this job if you study hard, [***otherwise\if not***] you won't.

Is there a difference between ***otherwise*** and ***if not***?

Comment: In your example, both mean exactly the same.  _Otherwise_ means _in different circumstances_, so it can be used in a wider range of sentences.

Comment: Perhaps it's helpful to see 'Otherwise' and 'If not' as deleted forms of 'If you choose to behave] **otherwise**' and '**If** [you do] **not** [study hard]'. They're both acceptable sentence-connectors showing an alternative scenario. _If you do A, B will happen. Otherwise/If not, B won't happen._

Answer (score 0):

*If not* is just the logical structure that's merged into the meaning of *else* -- a shortening of '**if** this is **not** the case'. As I recall, one popular programming language uses *if not*, while another uses *else* for what is essentially the same construct. I can't remember any more which ones it was, but there's lots of both around.

*Else* can't be used by itself in English, though *or else* is common. But that's not the same as *otherwise*. That means 'in another case', which includes more than just opposites, like *if not*, which has only two possibilities - yes and no. Thus, *otherwise* is the word to use when you don't want to restrict yourself to only two cases. If that's not an issue, then they're pretty much the same.

Comment: 'Else' by itself existed in informal UK dialect or regional speech until quite recently, maybe still does in places : _Wear a raincoat else you'll catch a cold!_

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms: Otherwise,
else,
if not,
alternatively,
or

All of the above assume a boolean case, whereas "and" would be a concatenation.
"this[could be a list] or that[could be a list])
alternatively
if not
otherwise

"Else" could be used as a concatenation or a boolean in english.

> What else can we do?

Operating on the aforementioned predicate, you should choose the most human readable option. All are correct usages. Language is defined by it's usage. It's usages are not defined by the language. Punctuation is defined by the language, because it relates to the sound of the spoken words and their inherent meanings within their scoped usage.

> Much akin to an open source repository, we choose what are considered
> canonically acceptable terms by popular opinion or delegation.
> Otherwise, we would have not have words for new inventions.
>
> Alternatively, if this is all just to much to bear and the world
> won't stop spinning, stop reading now. If not, continue unhindered;
> else, you may find yourself in a tizzy, scrolling stack exchange for hours looking for an answer you already know.